# Como direcionar o marcador google para uma página?

Tags: javascript

Eu conseguir implementar um marcador da google, e também conseguir implementar um link no marcador, quando o usuário clica no marcador ele é automaticamente direcionado para uma outra página, o único problema que quando o usuário clica no marcador é o componente que vai ser direcionado para outra pagina e não o site que vai para outra página, observe as duas figuras abaixo;

Figura 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Figura 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então como vocês podem ver quando o usuário clica no marcador invés de toda a pagina ser renderizada para outra página ele somente renderiza o componente interno.

Existe alguma forma no código Javascript de conseguir renderizar toda a pagina para ser direcionada para outra pagina invés do componente interno?

Esse é meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZBoBe3ObpfsAiLNq2aByZXKp4XRlUPYE" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = {lat: -23.6336946, lng: -46.73667330000001};
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:15,
    center:myLatLng
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);



  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'MDW Outsoucing Consultoria'
  });
/*
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -27.6041949, lng: -48.466012},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
  */

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
  window.location = 'https://www.mdwoutsourcing.com.br/quem-somos';
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: já tentou `window.top.location` no lugar de `window.location`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando `window.location` ou seja, ele irá substituir a janela atual, no caso o `map`. Para chegar no resultado esperado, use `window.location.href`.